# Stopping function execution in R when arguments are missing

Tags: r, function

I have a user-defined R function with 3 required arguments

```
func <- function(x, y, z) {
    some code... 
}
```

In case an argument is accidentally excluded from the function call, I simply invoke stop() as follows

```
if (missing(x)) {
 stop("Please provide a value for x.")
}

if (missing(y)) {
 stop("Please provide a value for y.")
}

if (missing(z)) {
 stop("Please provide a value for z.")
}
```

To check that this actually works I did the following:

```
func(y, z) # x missing
func(x, z) # y missing 
func(x, y) # z missing
```

However, only the last function call above returns the correct message. The preceding two functions both return "Please provide a value for z."

How is this possible when z is not missing from these calls?

Comment: `func(y, z)` is not the same as `func(y, z = z)`. To the point, whatever your variables are named outside of your function has no play on how they are referenced inside. Your `z` in the first two calls are in the place reserved for your `y=` argument, so your function will see them as such. If you want to take advantage of named arguments, you need to be specific when you call the function.

Comment: since you are not explicitly defining the objects here, as is it is likely being interpreted as `func(x = y, y = z, z = NULL)` and `func(x = x, y = z, z = NULL)`

Comment: Ahh yes... now I see. I always seem to forget about R's function argument handling